# regular expression for the random mix of numbers and letters

Tags: python, regex

```
a='a/20191101/6ca9ae66ebfe2c3040eb3df6148a5a4d.pdf'
b='a/20170310/402006fceb4cbad4c3bf6a89002249dd.pdf'
c='a/20161125/237ebceb094d5f92bbce65e2526339e0.pdf'
d='a/20180629/b990c7c01736f6cee10169140bb304b7.pdf'
```

The above strings are part of the pdf URL links, I want to use regex to match them, but I only get one part,

```
r'[a-z][/]\d+[/]'
```

I didn't know how to write the last part, which is a random mix of numbers and lowercase letters. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last portion is in lowercase hexadecimal, so we just need to create a group with both digits and the letters `a-f`, and then just add a `.pdf` at the end (remember to escape the period as it's a special character).

```regex
[a-z][/]\d+[/][\da-f]+\.pdf
```

I don't fully understand your use of brackets in cases where they're unnecessary. This version removes many of them and also works.

```regex
[a-z]/\d+/[\da-f]+\.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use wildcards and check for upper and lowercase letters and digits.  Or if you want to capture anything before .pdf, you can just use .*[.]pdf.  Use regex101.com to test your regex.  See this example:

```
[a-z]/\d+/[A-Za-z0-9]*[.]pdf

[a-z]/\d+/.*[.]pdf
```